# Laravel Eloquent Relationship Across 3 Tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have the following database table setup in an existing Laravel project I have started working on:

```
sports
    id 
    name

lines
    id 
    sport_id - Foreign Key (lines_sport_id_foreign)
    bet_id - Foreign Key (lines_bet_id_foreign)

bets
    id
    stake
```

With relationships set up like so:

Sport.php

```
public function lines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Line');
}
```

Line.php

```
public function bet()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Bet');
}

public function sport()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Sport');
}
```

Bet.php

```
public function lines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Line');
}
```

Now I need to be able to create a relationship between `Sport` and `Bet`. Specifically to

1. Get all bets on a sport (sport->bets)
2. And then also be able to sort the sports by the most staked (from the stake column on bets)

I have tried using Laravel's `hasManyThrough` method like so within `Sport`

```
public function bets()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Bet', 'App\Line');
}
```

But understandably I am getting a response of

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bets.line_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `bets`.*, `lines`.`sport_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `bets` inner join `lines` on `lines`.`id` = `bets`.`line_id` where `lines`.`sport_id` = 1)
```

If I was to call `App\Sport::find(1)->bets` as this expects the link between `lines` and `bets` on `bets` table, not the `lines` table as it currently is (I am unable to change the existing structure)

Is there anyway to get **all bets on a sport** along the lines of `$sport->bets`

And then secondly with that set up, then **sort all sports by the stake column on the bets table**? (ideally along the lines of `$sport->bets->orderBy('stake', 'desc')`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're **two** ways you can do this:

1. **[Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)**:
   where you can load the relationship `bet()` between models **line** and **bet** & you can make it exclusive to a certain sport with just a `where` condtition
     `return Line::with('bet')->where('sport_id',$sport_id)->get()`
        `$sport_id`:
        is the desired sport.
   The *downside* to this is the extra records of **Line** and the result cannot be ordered.
2. **Join Using** [**QueryBuilder**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins):
   Do a simple join between `lines` and `bets` with the same condition as before and include the order `stake`

   ```
   DB::table('lines')
       ->join('bets', 'lines.bet_id', '=', 'bet_id')
       ->select('lines.sport_id', 'bets.*')
       ->where('lines.sport_id',$sport_id)
       ->orderBy('bets.stake')
       ->get();
   ```

   A Little messy, But Here you can get the desired result (**all bets on a sport**).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like:

```
public function bets()
{
    return Bet::where('id', $this->lines->pluck('bet_id'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Norgul. However I am getting an error of `must return a relationship instance` when I try that `App\Sport::find(1)->bets`

Comment: What about if you add a `->get()` on where clause and call it as a method `->bets()`?